# CreateMutex issue in IIS 6

Tags: c++, iis, dll

I am new on IIS and we are using IIS 6 on Windows server 2003 and  facing some issue in our C++ dll.  CreateMutex API is failing . Does anyone  have any idea on?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you mean by fail? Does the CreateMutex() function return NULL or is the mutex not visible to other applications?

Comment: Its return NULL, I have doubt over the IIS security permissions. Does IIS have any permission constraint which are inheriting to the our DLL?

Comment: As @MSalters says below, what is the value returned from GetLastError() below?

Answer (score 0):

We don't, `GetLastError()` does.

Comment: I have doubt over the IIS security permissions. Does IIS have any permission constraint which are inheriting to the our DLL?

Comment: You didn't expect it to run as Administrator, I hope? But again, show code and in particular the error returned. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` ?